# Why is this bucket policy being shown as public

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am relatively new to AWS.

So recently, we creates an AWS S3 bucket through the AWS console. Then we set the following policy on the bucket:

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AddJPGImageFilter",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "IAM user ARN"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "bucket_name/*.jpg"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AddJPEGImageFilter",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": ""IAM user ARN""
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "bucket_name/*.jpeg"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AddPNGImageFilter",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": ""IAM user ARN""
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "bucket_name/*.png"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now from what I understand the above policy means the resource would be accessible (with the `S3:PutObject` action allowed) to only the IAM user ARN mentioned in the `Principal`. 
For it to be public, the `Principal` would need to be `*`.

Is my understanding correct ? 
If yes, why is the AWS console still showing the above bucket as `Public` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS web console has page caching issues. Try logout, clear your cache and re-login again.

Thanks
Sanjog

Comment: Awesome. That solved the issue. Thanks Sanjog. Btw, would be great if someone raises an issue with AWS about this.